# Share a volume between containers with DinD

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have a GitLab CI job that is currently using DinD. The CI runs inside a docker container.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- The CI job docker container, using dind, runs a docker container with a volume.

  ```
  docker run --name cvmfs --pid=host --user 0 --privileged --restart always -v /cvmfsmounts:/cvmfsmounts:rshared <our_registry>/vcs/cvmfs-automounter:master
  ```
- The CI job docker container runs another docker container using the same volume.

  ```
  docker run --rm -v /cvmfsmounts/cvmfs:/cvmfs:rslave busybox ls -lrt /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch
  ```

This is trying to automount a volume on the second docker container. It works when not using dind.

The main issue is this:

```
Error response from daemon: linux mounts: path /cvmfsmounts is mounted on / but it is not a shared mount
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?